# 1:1 mapping of variables to a dict with the names as keys

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, return

I have a very large amount of variables that I want to return as a dict with their variable names as keys. For example:

```
return {
    "foo": foo,
    "bar": bar,
    "baz": baz,
}
```

This is fine for maybe <=10 keys, but after that it becomes a complete mess. In my example I want to return ~100 variables like this.

Is there a one liner that I can use to do something like:

```
return x(foo, bar, baz)
```

Comment: Please post some part of your large list.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Sorry, I meant "amount", not "list".

Answer (score 2):

Using `locals()`:

```
def x(names, values):  
    return dict([ (n, values.get(n)) for n in names ])

x(["foo", "bar", "baz"], locals())
```